# Android set image as label in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Usually when I create a new project the default action bar has an icon, a title of text, an options button and in some activity a back button.

I'd like to replace the highlighted parts (default icon and title)  with a single image (my custom logo, a rectangular png) without losing the back button and the option's one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the the title

This will remove the title

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.show();
```

The icon is your application logo.
Check here on how to change your application logo

http://envyandroid.com/archives/301/change-the-android-app-icon

Answer (score 0):

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
        ...
    </activity>
    <!-- A child of the main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:icon="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Adding this to your manifest will let you set your own custom items in place. Replace the package and drawables as per your choice.

Reference taken from http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html